# My code is not able to pass one of the test cases because it is producing a wrong value, which I can't find why. What could be the problem in my code?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, if-statement, implementation

Question - Petya loves lucky numbers. We all know that lucky numbers are the positive integers whose decimal representations contain only the lucky digits 4 and 7. For example, numbers 47, 744, 4 are lucky and 5, 17, 467 are not.

Unfortunately, not all numbers are lucky. Petya calls a number nearly lucky if the number of lucky digits in it is a lucky number. He wonders whether number n is a nearly lucky number.

Input - The only line contains an integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 1018).

Please do not use the %lld specificator to read or write 64-bit numbers in С++. It is preferred to use the cin, cout streams or the %I64d specificator.

Output -  Print on the single line "YES" if n is a nearly lucky number. Otherwise, print "NO" (without the quotes).

Question Link - https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/110/A

My code -

```
int main(){
    int a,b=0;
    cin >> a;
    string x = to_string(a);
    for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++){
        if(x[i]=='4' || x[i]=='7'){
            b++;
        }
    }
    cout << b;
    if(b==4 || b==7){
        cout << "YES";
    }else{cout << "NO";}
}
```

It is passing numerous test cases but there is one which it fails. When the integer is 4744000695826 , the value of my B is 5 therefore the output is NO. I am not understanding why is the value of B = 5, whereas it should be equal to 4 and even my code seems to be working that way. What could be the possible problems?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/x6hx3r

Comment: Do you know what limits an integer has?

Comment: No, what are those?

Comment: @ProgrammerGuy `std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << std::endl;` – Overflowing or underflowing these boundaries will invoke undefined-behavior.

Comment: What happens if I exceed the limits? @TedLyngmo

Comment: Why read it as an int then convert it to a string and never use the int again? Just read it as a string to begin with.

Comment: When I asked the rotrical question I had forgotten how it felt to be a newcommer. Good thing I got to upvote before Community shut it down.

Comment: "_rotrical_"  should have been "_rhetorical_"  - even though "rotrical" is a bit more amusing

Answer (score 2):

Integers have certain limits, and exceeding the limits can cause undefined behavior, so instead of int, long long will be used.
Updated code -

```
int main(){
    long long a,b=0;
    cin >> a;
    string x = to_string(a);
    for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++){
        if(x[i]=='4' || x[i]=='7'){
            b++;
        }
    }
    cout << b;
    if(b==4 || b==7){
        cout << "YES";
    }else{cout << "NO";}
}
```

Comment: Quick study! Have an upvote!

Comment: **ProTip!** You can use `!cin.good()` to verify if the value assignment was successful.

Comment: What @RohanBari mentioned is good. You have table of [state combinations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) you can look at (it's down at the bottom on that page).